# Xamarin data binding how to bind the value times two

Tags: xamarin, data-binding

I'm learning Xamarin Data Binding and learning the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBinding"
             x:Class="DataBinding.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label" Text="twisting" FontSize="70" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=slider}"
               Rotation="{Binding Path=Value}">
        </Label>
        <Slider x:Name="slider" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Maximum="360" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        </Slider>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I want to double the twisting speed so I modify the code:

```
<Label x:Name="label" Text="twisting" FontSize="70" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=slider}"
       Rotation="{Binding Path=Value*2}">
</Label>
```

But it doesn't work at all. I know the below solution works but I want a solution relating to the above:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Maximum="720" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
</Slider>
```

How to do it?

**UPDATE1**

I customize a converter as the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DataBinding
{
    public class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var speed = value as int?;
            return speed * 2;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and modify the xaml as the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBinding"
             x:Class="DataBinding.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label" Text="twisting" FontSize="70" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=slider}"
               Rotation="{Binding Path, Converter={StaticResource  myCo

    nverter}}">
            </Label>
            <Slider x:Name="slider" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Maximum="360" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            </Slider>
        </StackLayout>
        <ContentPage.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:MyValueConverter x:Key="myConverter"></local:MyValueConverter>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContentPage.Resources>
    </ContentPage>
```

But my converter doesn't work properly and what is more, I made a breakpoint and found that the `Convert` function even not getting triggered.

**UPDATE2**

I found out the reason, the label in XAML should be the below:

```
<Label x:Name="label" Text="twisting" FontSize="70" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=slider}"
                   Rotation="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource  myConverter}}">
</Label>
```

and the type of value inside the Convert function is double instead of string:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
       var tmp = (Double)value*2;
       return tmp;
}
```

Then it works.

Comment: use a ValueConverter

Comment: @Jason Thanks, it works!